# Correct way to use gerunds?

Tags: tenses

I'm having a debate on whether it is better to use gerund or past tense in my science report. Please have a look at the sentences below.

1. When blowing into the solution, CO2 was introduced to the test tube, causing the colour to change from yellow to red.
2. When blowing into the solution, CO2 was introduced to the test tube which caused the colour to change from yellow to red.

To my knowledge, "Blowing" in both sentences served as a gerund which did not affect the overall tense of the observation. However, after setting the time with "was introduced", I'm wondering whether it is ok to use another gerund (causing ) or better to keep using past tense (Caused).

If the use of gerund is acceptable, should it always be separated by a comma from the previous phrase which was written in past tense?

Many thanks!

Comment: Two different issues: First, either "causing ..." or "which caused" is perfectly acceptable; and neither requires a comma.  Second,. "**When** blowing into the solution, CO2 was introduced" implies that these were two **separate** events which both happened at the same time.  I would have written "**By** blowing into ..."; or "CO2 was introduced to the test tube by blowing into the solution, causing ..."

Comment: None of these participles are gerunds. A gerund is not just any word ending in *-ing*. A gerund is specifically a present participle that is used as a noun. Both *blowing* and *causing* are not being used as nouns here, but purely as verbs. With that out of the way, 1 and 2 are equally fine but seeing how this is a science report, one can be preferable or indeed mandated over the other, depending on what particular style guide you have to adhere to in your specific domain.

Comment: Thank you! If both blowing and causing are not being used as nouns here, what is the correct way to mix present and past tense together? I always thought verb tenses should be consistent throughout the whole sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You could change *blowing* (present) into *blown* (past) to keep those tenses consistent.

> CO2, blown (past tense) through the solution, was introduced(past) into the test tube, causing (present --because it always has this effect) the colour to change from yellow to red.

This also corrects the ungrammatical hanging participle 'blowing'.